# Ошибка сборки Release при использование EPPLus

Tags: android, xamarin, forms, epplus

Друзья, работаю в Xamarin Forms в общем проекте установил EppPlus для работы с Excel  при Debug сборке все работает отлично, но при сборке Release вылазит данная ошибка, как исправить ?

Спасибо заранее, я в Xamarin Forms навичок

[image: Текст ошибки]

Answer (score 0):

Решение - изменения параметров связывания  в настройках сборки Release проект